# Mudanças nas regras de negócios da Apple

Tags: ionic, mobile, ionic2, ionic3, apple

Bom dia. Essa semana andei lendo sobre algumas mudanças nas regras de negócios da Apple para 2018, onde aplicativos que trabalham com o modelo white label não serão mais suportados. Andei lendo sobre o que seria um modelo white label, mas não consegui ter um entendimento muito bom.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: O IONIC segue esse modelo white label? Ainda vou conseguir publicar na Apple Store um aplicativo desenvolvido com IONIC?

Att,
Maurício.

Answer (score 1):

Essa atualização a que vc se refere está descrita no seguinte item da App Store Review Guidelines:

4.2.6 Apps created from a commercialized template or app generation service will be rejected.

Ou seja, basicamente são aplicativos que são originados de templates. A Apple implementou essa regra para conter basicamente duas situações:

1. Empresas que desenvolvem e comercializam geradores de apps básicas que são apenas um template onde são trocados logos e textos.
2. Apps mais complexas que são desenvolvidas para atender diversos clientes diferentes, mas que a mesma app é clonada para cada cliente.

Esse segundo caso gerou muito protesto por parte das empresas desenvolvedoras e a regra foi atualizada para:

4.2.6 Apps created from a commercialized template or app generation service will be rejected unless they are submitted directly by the provider of the app’s content. These services should not submit apps on behalf of their clients and should offer tools that let their clients create customized, innovative apps that provide unique customer experiences. Another acceptable option for template providers is to create a single binary to host all client content in an aggregated or “picker” model, for example as a restaurant finder app with separate customized entries or pages for each client restaurant, or as an event app with separate entries for each client event.

Ou seja, a recomendação dada pela própria apple é q, ou cada app seja publicada na conta de seu respectivo cliente (o gerador de conteúdo), ou que seja publicada uma app única com login ou seleção de cada cliente.

Neste artigo o caso está bem explicado: https://macmagazine.com.br/2017/12/21/apple-revisa-regra-importante-da-app-store-referente-a-apps-criados-com-base-em-modelos/

E respondendo à sua pergunta, o fato de sua app ser em Ionic não tem haver exatamente com a regra.

Comment: Boa resposta. Tanto não tem a ver com Ionic que no fórum da apple vc encontra programadores que fizeram apps nativos usando swift que tiveram o mesmo problema, em vários países. Tanto em apps quanto em jogos.